# i got Runtime Error for my code ,can anyone help me to find out where i am wrong

Tags: java, error-handling, stack, runtime, infinite-loop

i am getting  Runtime Error - NZEC for my code given below.I am not been able to understand why.Can anyone help me out with that.

**problem statement:** Various signal towers are present in a city.Towers are aligned in a straight horizontal line(from left to right) and each tower transmits a signal in the right to left direction.Tower A shall block the signal of Tower B if Tower A is present to the left of Tower B and Tower A is taller than Tower B. So,the range of a signal of a given tower can be defined as :

{(the number of contiguous towers just to the left of the given tower whose height is less than or equal to the height of the given tower) + 1}.

You need to find the range of each tower.

INPUT

First line contains an integer T specifying the number of test cases.

Second line contains an integer n specifying the number of towers.

Third line contains n space separated integers(H[i]) denoting the height of each tower.

OUTPUT

Print the range of each tower (separated by a space).

Constraints

1 <= T <= 10

2 <= n <= 10^6

1 <= H[i] <= 10^8

**my code**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;



class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       while(t!=0)
       {
           int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

           int arr[]=new int[n-1];
           int atest[]=new int[n-1];

           for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
               arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
           }

           for(int j=n-1;j>=0;j--)
           {
               int count=0;
              int temp=j-1;
               while(arr[j]>=arr[temp])
               {

                   count++;
                   temp--;  

               }
               atest[j]=count;
           }

           for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
           {
              System.out.println(atest[k]+1);  
           }

           t--;

       }



    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NZEC runtime error in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183624/nzec-runtime-error-in-java)

Comment: Two problems:
1. You maybe creating too many arrays within the while loop
2. You are using Scanner as well BufferedReader which might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
       int arr[]=new int[n-1];
       int atest[]=new int[n-1];

       for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
           arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
       }
```

because array length is n-1 (arr.length = n-1)

that is why you're getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.